# boost regex exp how to match multiple optional cases

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have a string like this format `{Name,Address,(PhoneNumber1)*}`; `(PhoneNumber1)*` means PhoneNumber can appear 0 to infinite times.

I want to get texts of `Name`, `Address`, and all the `PhoneNumber` if they present in the text.

for example:

`{Name1,Addr1}` will return `Name1` as group 1, `Addr1` as group 2

`{Name1,Addr1,Phone1,Phone2}` will return `Name1` as group 1, `Addr1` as group2, `Phone1` as group3, `Phone2` as group4, etc.

Comment: *0 to infinite times.* - Upper bound sounds interesting. Anyways, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried `^\{(\w+?),(\w+?)(?:,(\w+))*\}$` but it does not capture `Phone1` when text is `{Name1, Addr1, Phone1,Phone2}`

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to capture the repeating phone numbers unless the regex itself is applied multiple times. If you rely on repetition of a capture group within the regex, the capture group will always match the last instance matched.

The "trick" I'm aware of to deal with this is to use alternation to capture the initial sequence, as follows:

```
(?:\A{(\w+),(\w+)|(\w+?)(?:,|}\Z))
```

as shown in this [fiddle](http://rubular.com/r/KsJ3Bgr2qU) (I'm not aware of a regex fiddle supporting c++, so I used rubular). It will match some non-conforming examples (e.g. those not terminating with a `}`), but it should match all the conforming ones.